# Eclipse MARS - Cannot install Android ADT Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I try to install the Android Developer Tool, I get the following error.

> Unable to read repository at
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml. Unable to read
>   repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
>   Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

I'm running Eclipse MARS 64bit version. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you install from eclipse or with the exe from the android website

Comment: Are you accessing internet through proxy ?...check your connection settings for Android SDK manager...if yes then you need to configure your proxy settings there also